# is concatenating embeddings of different dimension as input to two tower model valid?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, recommender-system

I'm trying to build a two tower retrieval system for recommender system. Sudden question popped into my head, when concatenating all embeddings then sending it off to dense layer, does embeddings with higher dimension have higher importance?

Also if I'm concatenating numerical features, does it need to be scaled so that it is similar to value range of categorical embeddings? 
`For example: embedding of categorical features embedded with values in range [-0.5, 0.5] making one embedding as [0.33, 0.123,-0.23, ...]. For numerical features since it has been min-max scaled it ranges from [0,1]. So do I need to re-scale numerical features to be in range [-0.5, 0.5]?`

In tensorflow tutorial, they seem to not care about it https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/featurization

I want to know the reasoning behind the answer, also link to reference will be helpful :)